# A question about the function $S(n)=\sum_{p\le\sqrt n}\Big\lfloor\frac n p\Big\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let's define the function
$$S(n)=\sum_{p\le\sqrt n}\Big\lfloor\frac n p\Big\rfloor$$
where $\,p\,$ is prime and $\,n\gt4$.

A computation of $\,S(n)\,$ suggests that $\,S(n)=S(n-1)\,$ if and only if $\,n\,$ is a prime.

**I ask the reason of this behavior.**

Many thanks.

Comment: Your claim is true. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and explain what you've tried.)

**Hint:** Show that if $n$ is prime, then $ \lfloor \frac{n}{a} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{n-1}{a} \rfloor $ for $ a < n$.

**Hint:** Show that if $n$ is composite, then show that $ \lfloor \frac{n}{a} \rfloor  \geq \lfloor \frac{n-1}{a} \rfloor $, with strict inequality for certain $a$.

Hence, the result follows.